# Download javascript data to a file in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I have code to download javascript variables as files but it is not working in IE8, how would I do this in IE8?

```
function download(filename, text) {
    var pom = document.createElement('a');
    pom.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
    pom.setAttribute('download', filename);

    document.body.appendChild(pom)
    pom.click();

    // Remove anchor from body
    document.body.removeChild(pom)
}
```

Comment: You can send the data to a server-side script that responds with the correct download headers.

Answer (score 1):

In IE 8 and 9 data URIs can only be used for images, but not for navigation or Javascript generated file downloads.

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Disadvantages

you can achieve the download with server side processing of the file.